# Best practise - C# .Net console app POST to a url

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, post, console-application

What would be the best approach to make a POST request to a web service url, in a Console App?

I tried using WebClient.uploadstring but it fails whenever the POSTed data is slightly bigger.

I tried HTTPClient but it's an async call.. so I had to additionally use ManualResetEvent to keep it alive till the server response is received..

I'd like to know what's the best way to do this. Please let me know if mpre info is required.

Comment: What size post data are you sending? What is the error message you receive when it fails using WebClient.UploadString?

Comment: @juzzbott it's just 76674 bytes.. it gives me a 400 bad request error. But when i try the exact same json using rest clients, it gives a 200.

Comment: 76674 bytes is small, not large. You must be doing something else wrong. However, we can't help you because you didn't _show us your code_.

Comment: 76674 bytes is nothing really, Using a tool such as fiddler, does the 400 bad request give any further additional information as to why the error was returned? The 400 Bad Request could also mean that the post data was invalid. An example of the code would be helpful.

Comment: @Juzzbott  when i try the exact same json using rest clients, it gives a 200. even with fiddler. infact, it gives me a 200 when i post just the first two items of the list, but not the whole list. and the exact same json (of the full list) works fine with HttpClient, (only problem being it makes async requests which i dont prefer..)

thats why i specifically said that larger post data fails using webClient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `HTTPClient`'s `PostAsync(url, content).Result` which waits till it gets a response! neat stuff..

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "huge"?

If you are posting large amounts of data to the URL, then you could be exceeding the maximum request size, in which case no method of requesting the URL with that amount of post data will work.